# Load block's content with AJAX

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

What is the best way, installing as few modules as possible, to load content into a custom block?

My understanding is that an easy way to do it is by creating a page callback that calls `drupal_json_output()` and then add a Drupal JavaScript behavior to query that page and receive the JSON content.

Are there better ways? Is there any already built-in functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Ajax Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks) module might do what you're looking for.